# Opacidade em imagem com tag MAP

Tags: html, css

Tenho essa página:

http://comunicacaointerage.com.br/paginas/DiskBanner/diskbanner.html

Nela, a imagem está com as tags `<area>` para colocar link sobre cada um das formas. O problema é que o pessoal do atendimento quer que quando clicar no número `1` por exemplo, o resto fique com uma opacidade. Tem alguma possibilidade ?

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer não é possível amigo.
A única forma de fazer o que você quer é usando SVG.
Faça uma combinação de CSS + jQuery e você conseguirá fazer o que quer.

Sugestões:
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/